# I can't find what does: Implicit declaration of function 'InitRenderingGLES' is invalid in C99 means

Tags: opengl-es

well, its been few days that I have been trying to solve code issues in Xcode with no prior experience at all, but a common sense. will appreciate some help in a bug I cannot find an answer to: I have many errors with something that is called openGLS: 1. updated my iPhone 6s to 13.6 OS version and now its is still occurring.

[screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgTws.png)